# Pandas Subtracting between two Data Frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

DFOne

```
 1. ID-1  NumberValueCol1- 10 
 2. ID-2  NumberValueCol1--11
 3. ID-3  NumberValueCol1--20
 4. ID-4  NumberValueCol1--13
 5. ID-5  NumberValueCol1--15
```

DFTwo

```
 1. ID-1  NumberValueCol1- 5
 2. ID-2  NumberValueCol1--7
 3. ID-3  NumberValueCol1--9
 4. ID-4  NumberValueCol1--6
 5. ID-5  NumberValueCol1--3
```

I need to subtract DFOne.NumberValueCol1 from each value in DFTwo until I get the least difference.

the first iteration would subtract DFOne.NumberValueCol1--10, from every value in DFTwo and that would result in

ID Results (DFOne.NumberValueCol1, 10 value each DFTwo.NumberValueCol2 values)

```
 1. Result - 5
 2. Result - 3
 3. Result - 1
 4. Result - 4
 5. Result - 7
```

In this case, ID 3--DFTwo.NumberValueCol2 (9), yields the smallest difference of 1.  So I would like to map this value to 
DFOne.NumberValueCol1 -- 10.

The second iteration would start with ID 2, DFOne.NumberValueCol1 value 11.  However, Instead of starting the subtraction 
from the beginning of DFTwo.NumberValueCol2, it would start at the next available ID from the point that there was a match.
So, since there was a match with ID 3, the next starting point would be ID 4, and it would do the same as the first logic to get the smallest difference

I hope this is not too confusing.  I come from the t-sql world, so I'm trying to understand how to do this type of calculation using Pandas instead of the traditional sql server cursors.

Comment: post the final expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is summarized as:

1. Find the maximum value in DFTwo, subtract that from the first value in DFOne.
2. Using the index of the maximum value in DFTwo, slice DFTwo onwards from that index.
3. Go to Step 1, using the second row of DFone.

A working example:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = {'id': [1,2,3,4,5], 'value': [10,11,20,13,15]}
df2 = {'id': [1,2,3,4,5], 'value': [5,7,9,6,3]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=df2)
print("DFTwo")
print(df2)
print('\n')
min_index = 0
df_output = []
for i in df1['value']:
    try:
        new_val = i - max(df2['value'])
        max_index = int(df2['id'][df2['value'] == max(df2['value'])].values)
        df2 = df2.iloc[max_index:,]
        df_output.append( (max_index, new_val) )
    except:
        break
print("Output")
print(pd.DataFrame(df_output, columns = ['id','result']))
```

However, we run into the issue here that DFTwo is eventually *nil*.

```
2 -- 1
   id  value
3   4      6
4   5      3
0 -- 5
   id  value
4   5      3
0 -- 17
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [id, value]
Index: []
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Tyler/Desktop/pd_test.py", line 11, in <module>
    new_val = i - max(df2['value'])
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

The output with the new except clause:

```
DFTwo
   id  value
0   1      5
1   2      7
2   3      9
3   4      6
4   5      3


Output
   id  result
0   3       1
1   4       5
```

Ostensibly, this won't be an issue in your real-world use case, as DFTwo is large enough to support this slicing? Without more information on the actual business logic, this is my best attempt.

Comment: Steps would be:
1. DFOne first value, subtract from DFTwo
2. Match the smallest result from the two
3. Go to the next record of DFOne and start over

Final result set should contain all of the matches.  It can't be the max value of DFTwo, because the next DFOne record might 
be a match to the previous values.  


final result would be, ID being from DFTwo
ID 3, Result 1   (this is 10 DfOne value -9 DfTwo Value)
ID 4, Result 5   (this is 11 DfOne value-6 DfTwo Value)

Comment: "It can't be the max value of DFTwo, because the next DFOne record might be a match to the previous values"
-----
What? If you want the minimum of a set of differences (x1 - x2), where the first value (x1) is constant, then you can simply use the pair where x2 is greatest.

Comment: I have changed the code to better reflect your original question, please review and let me know if this is closer to your expectation.

Comment: Hi Konchshell,  Thank you for responding to my question.  Based on the requirements that I gave in this posting, yes, your answer can get me on the right start.  My business use case is a little different, I was trying to be generic in my posting.  Thank you again for your post!